# How to Copy Merge Field From Browser & Paste Into MS-Word?

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word, mailmerge

How can I copy a Mail Merge Field from any browser and paste it into MS-Word? I'm trying to build a web page where all you have to do is click a button or link to copy a Mail Merge Field from the page, and be able to paste it into MS-Word.

I've written HTML and Javascript to accomplish this, but it only works in IE. See code at bottom. (I'm using clipboard.js.)

I'm limited by the following:

1. It must be idiot proof simple for the end user. Basically a simple click to copy so they can paste it into word.
2. No addons.
3. No word macros or vb code.
4. No keyboard shortcuts EG: ctrl F9

The problem is when I copy from Chrome the html text in the clipboard is different from IE, and it is changing the styles so that when I paste into Word it just sees it as text rather than a field code.

Below are samples of the clipboard html text that I retrieved using a special paste into notepad++.

**Internet Explorer**

```
Version:1.0
StartHTML:000000219
EndHTML:000000626
StartFragment:000000350
EndFragment:000000568
StartSelection:000000350
EndSelection:000000568
SourceURL: .../MiniTag.html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY><TABLE><TBODY><TR><TD><!--StartFragment--><DIV id="divAccountNumber"><!--StartFragment--><P class="MsoNormal"><SPAN style='mso-field-code: "MERGEFIELD AccountNumber";'><SPAN style="mso-no-proof: yes;">«AccountNumber»</SPAN></SPAN></P><!--EndFragment--></DIV><!--EndFragment--></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></BODY></HTML>
```

**Chrome Clipboard**

```
Version:0.9
StartHTML:0000000173
EndHTML:0000000684
StartFragment:0000000209
EndFragment:0000000648
SourceURL: .../MiniTag.html
<html>
<body>
<!--StartFragment--><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;; font-size: medium; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; display: inline !important; float: none;">«AccountNumber»</span><!--EndFragment-->
</body>
</html>
```

**HTML and Javascript Code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
 <HEAD></HEAD>
 <BODY>
 <!-- 1. Define some markup -->
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td><div id="divAccountNumber"></div></td>
   <td><button id="btnAccountNumber" class="btn" data-clipboard-action="copy">Copy</button></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </pre>
 
 <!-- 2. Include library -->
    <script src="./dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>

 <!-- 3. Instantiate clipboard -->
    <script>
 
 var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn',{
  target: function(trigger){
   document.getElementById('divAccountNumber').innerHTML = getMiniHtml();
   return document.getElementById('divAccountNumber');
  }
 });

 function getMiniHtml()
 {
  //&#171; is « 
  //&#187; is » 
  //so on UI, mail merge tag will rendered as «AccountNumber»
  var tagText = "";
  tagText += "<!--StartFragment-->"
  tagText += "<p class='MsoNormal'><span style='mso-field-code:\"MERGEFIELD AccountNumber\"'><span style='mso-no-proof:yes'>&#171;AccountNumber&#187;</span></span></p>";
  tagText += "<!--EndFragment-->";
  return tagText; 
 }

    clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
  alert('copied');  
  console.log(e);
    });

    clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
  alert('error occurred');
        console.log(e);
    });
 </script>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```